# Why the Arrowheads[] in ParametricPlot sometimes works and sometimes doesn't?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

It is about the system of ODE. My code is as below:

```
A = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}};
Eigenvalues[A]
X[t_] = {x[t], y[t]};
system = X'[t] == A.X[t];
sol = DSolve[system, {x, y}, t]
particularsols = 
  Partition[
   Flatten[Table[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol /. {C[1] -> i, 
       C[2] -> j}, {i, -1, 1, 6/10}, {j, -1, 1, 6/10}]], 2];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0., 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image: circular]

If I changed `A` from `{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}` to `{{4, -6}, {1, -1}}`, the arrows disappear as below:

[image]

Why and how can I get it fixed? Thanks.

Comment: using `PlotRange -> All` in the second case suggests that all the arrowheads fall outside the range `{{-2,2},{-2,2}}` .

Comment: if you use, say,  `Arrowheads[PadRight[{0.0, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07}, 600]]` some arrowheads show up.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I tried `PadRight` with `600` by zerolizing different initial values of the `0.07`s and now I understand why it works. That manipulates the position of the arrow corresponding to the portion of the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `A = {{4, -6}, {1, -1}};` and `PlotRange -> All`

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

which suggests all the arrowheads fall outside `{{-2,2},{-2,2}}` when we use `PlotRange -> {-2, 2}`.

An easy fix is to modify the coordinates of `Line` primitives to remove coords outside the desired range:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.}], 
   Arrow[Select[x, -2 <= #[[1]] <= 2 && -2 <= #[[2]] <= 2 &]]}
```

[image]

An alternative quick-and-dirty way is to add *many* more arrowheads:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, ImageSize -> Large] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[PadRight[{0.0, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07}, 600]], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

**Why is this happening?**

`ParametricPlot` produces the same `Line` primitives regardless of the setting for `PlotRange` as we can see using four examples with different settings:

```
pp1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}];
pp2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}];
pp3 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Automatic];
pp4 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[particularsols], {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All];

Apply[Equal][Cases[#, _Line, All] & /@ {pp1, pp2, pp3, pp4}]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Option setting for `PlotRange` is used by the `FrontEnd` to display the desired portion of graphics primitives.